# Can I run a mixer off a battery?

Tags: mixer, amplifier, battery

I am in India, and there's no RadioShack equivalent here ... running to the corner store isn't an option to get components. If I need to get components I'll have to order them online. 
So. My question:

I have a small battery powered 25W amplifier/speaker combo. KustomSound CB25X, with two 6V 4.5Ah SLA batteries wired in series for 12V. Fully charged, the voltage seems to be close to 13V.

I also have a mixer - Yamaha MG06X, which runs off a 12V wall wart. The voltage off the wall wart is 12.3V.

The mixer is rated for 24W but it's unlikely I'll ever be using it at full power. Same goes for the speaker.

I also got myself a little preassembled LM2577 DC/DC switching voltage booster from online.

Can I run the mixer off of the amp battery with the DC/DC booster? Can it tolerate a volt or so above its rated 12V e.g. 13-14V when the battery is fully charged? (Because that DC/DC chip can't lower the voltage, unfortunately.)

Alternatively: can I wire the DC/DC booster across just one battery? Will that be bad for the amp or the batteries or the mixer? EDIT: I have been informed this is not good for battery life. So ignore this idea.

Comment: Wait, what do you actually need the DC/DC booster for, now?

Comment: @leftaroundabout To keep the voltage for the mixer at a steady 12V as the battery voltage drops. So I was only worried in case the excess 1 or 2 volts from the fully charged battery might cause a problem, but evidently not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer: yes, it appears to work. The question now becomes “how long will it last” so I'll wait for time to tell xD

Comment: Aaand the answer to that is, over 5 hours! At low power. Which is how I'll generally be using it. Success!

Comment: good to hear that boloar! please mark your question as 'answered' by clicking the V symbol left.

Comment: @arnoud-traa I tried to do that earlier, and was notified by a popup that I must wait several hours before I can accept my answer for my question. So I'll do it tomorrow.